# Understanding Riesz's Lemma for finite-dimensional spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

[About an extension of Riesz' Lemma for normed spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304719/about-an-extension-of-riesz-lemma-for-normed-spaces?rq=1) I came across this question about Riesz lemma and for the highest voted answer the author constructed a sequence with limit point $\|u_n\|=1$ in the compact unit ball. Can we just use the closed ball instead of compact since we just need the limit point to be in the unit ball?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question.  In particular, it is unclear what you mean by "a sequence with limit point $\|u_n\|=1$"

Comment: So I guess what my question is since the unit ball there is already closed, we can find the limit point of the sequence in that ball and thus lead to a sequence with $\|u_n\|=1$, why we still need compact?

Comment: The fact that the unit ball is closed does **not** mean that we can find a limit point to a sequence contained within the unit ball.  In particular, the sequence might not have any limit points.

Comment: Uhm how about a subsequence? Can we find a subsequence with limit point in unit ball if the unit ball is only closed?

Comment: No.  For a classical counterexample, in the (infinite-dimensional) space $\ell^2$ the "standard basis" has no convergent subsequence, and has no limit points as a sequence.